# No such file to load -- spec in merb

Tags: ruby, gemfile, merb

I have created an app in merb. My Gemfile has

```
gem "rspec", :require => "spec"
```

If I run the `rake -T` or `rake routes`, my rake task is aborted with the above error.

If the gem is not mentioned in the Gemfile then the error is

```
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- spec/rake/spectask
```

Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

> solved the problem by specifying the gem version for rspec as gem "rspec", "1.2.11",:require => "spec" :) . the merb version is 1.1.3 – Prasad Surase Jul 29 '11 at 9:22